# Connecting to rethinkdb (or any other app running on an http port) from the Docker OS X beta

Tags: macos, docker, portforwarding

I've installed [the Docker for Mac beta](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) which allows you to use docker commands directly. I want to try to run `rethinkdb` through docker, so I've followed the instructions of [the rethinkdb docker container docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/) and done the following:

```
docker run --name some-rethink -v "$PWD:/data" -d rethinkdb
```

This works, and I can see the container with `docker ps` and start shell with `docker exec -it /bin/bash`

However, I can't connect to the admin panel on my Mac directly with their suggestion

```
$BROWSER "http://$(docker inspect --format \
  '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some-rethink):8080"
```

This essentially amounts to `google-chrome http://172.17.0.2:8080/`, but this doesn't work. I asked around and was told

> You can't use the docker private ip address space to access the ports
>
> You have to forward them to the mac

However, I'm not sure how to do this as I don't have any port forwarding tools I'm familiar with such as `ssh` on the container itself. Using the suggested port forwarding command in the rethinkdb container docs `ssh -fNTL ...` but with `localhost` instead of `remote` does not work.

How can I connect to the rethinkdb admin panel through http with the `docker` beta on a Mac?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try forwarding the container port using the `-p` flag in the `docker run` command, e.g.:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 --name some-rethink -v "$PWD:/data" -d rethinkdb`

and then it should be accessible on localhost,

`google-chrome http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Relevant `docker run` docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/expose-incoming-ports